# Getting the greater of two values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table. This table has two tables: Order and OrderInProgress. These two tables have similar structures:

```
Order[InProgress]
-----------------
ID (uniqueidentifier)
CreateDate
...
```

I need to get the latest Order or OrderInProgress

```
DECLARE @latestOrderID uniqueidentifier
@latestOrderID = ?
```

How do I set @latestOrderID to the most recent Order or OrderInProgress ID? I can't figure out how to do this in SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: how about having a little attempt?

Comment: Do you need to know which table possesses the most recent order ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which should be more efficient whenever it matters.

```
   select top 1 ID from (
        select top 1 ID from Order order by ID desc
      union all
        select top 1 ID from OrderInProgress order by ID desc
    ) T
    order by ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @latestOrderID = ID FROM [Order] ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'Order' tablename, max(ID) max_id FROM Order
UNION
SELECT 'OrderInProgress' tablename, max(ID) max_id FROM OrderInProgress
) maxes ORDER BY max_id DESC
```